# use a Helper inside a controller that does not extend AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have created a controller that extends TCPDF to be able to customise a bunch of stuffs ,
 also  i need to use inside it  Helpers .
knowing that i can not have multiple inheritance in php ,  i tried to create an instance of the view inside  the constructor of my new controller  to grab the target Helper

like this

```
class NewPDF extends TCPDF{

    public function __construct()
    {
     $fakeView=new View($this);
     $htmlHelper=$fakeView->loadHelper("Html");
     # some code ..... parent::__construct()
    }

}
```

it does not work . it gave me weird errors !!!

how can i use a helper inside a controller that does not extend AppController ?

Answer (score 1):

> it does not work . it gave me weird errors !!!

It does because **you're doing everything totally wrong**. That you want to extend a controller with a helper and even throw a view in the mix tells me you have seriously **no** idea at all how a MVC framework works.

- [Design patterns in general (MVC is one)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)
- [Wikipedia about MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [CakePHP book explanation of MVC](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html)
- [Random Google article about MVC](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488)
- [Start over here when you understoog the above](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#getting-started)

At least I'm not going to write in detail what is wrong because like I said, *everything* is wrong, start with the very basics. The links will explain how to do it right. What you wrote shows a huge lack of knowledge that can't be fixed by a short answer.

Comment: i am just asking how can i use a helper inside other part which does not cake about  the MVC pattern